# Using DAX to count running total but it doesn't count the same values

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to DAX and I tried to calculate the running total for the variable of media so I can see how many media counts for 80% of all the items created. The result is problematic as the rows with the same values were not cumulated:

https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/949411iA4178E7D5977C6B7/image-dimensions/2000?v=v2&px=-1 (The example of the issue, can not add here directly)

My Dax is as follows:

```
Pareto =
VAR Total_Unique_Item =
   CALCULATE(
   DISTINCTCOUNT(Data[HeadlineID]),
   ALLSELECTED(Data)
    )
VAR Current_Total_Unique_Item = DISTINCTCOUNT(Data[HeadlineID])
VAR SummarizedTable =
   SUMMARIZE(
   ALLSELECTED(Data),
   Data[Media],
   "Unique_Item_Count", DISTINCTCOUNT(Data[HeadlineID])
)
VAR CumulativeSum =
   SUMX (
   FILTER(SummarizedTable, [Unique_Item_Count] >= Current_Total_Unique_Item),
   [Unique_Item_Count])
RETURN
CumulativeSum/Total_Unique_Item
```

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!